# How is 'synchronized' related to ReentrantLock?

Tags: java, concurrency

From what I have read, *`synchronized`* block of code means intrinsic re-entrant lock of an object, and `ReentrantLock` is an abstraction to achieve re-entrance. Is there a need to use `ReentrantLock` other than calling `lock()` and `unlock()` methods from different methods, pieces of codes?

Comment: this is why docs exist : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html

Comment: Well, you can synchronize only on one monitor, whereas you can "guard" several objects with a `ReentrantLock`; that is the main difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Documentation of ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)

> A reentrant mutual exclusion Lock with the same basic behavior and
>   semantics as the implicit monitor lock accessed using synchronized
>   methods and statements, but with extended capabilities.

Those extended capabilities are related to the monitoring of the synchronization, as well as customization of the behavior. Looking at the method list should speak for itself.